# How do I make regexp i Ruby that doesnt require matches / optional matches?

Tags: ruby, regex

Im trying to create a regexp that matches parts of some strings. 
I doesnt have to match everypart, but at least one ( which it always will )

I want: Name and Year and / or Season/Episode.

Lets say I have these strings:

1. i.want.this.as.name.2014.s01e02
2. i still want a this 2010
3. i also want this
4. I still want this.S05E23.720p.HDTV.X264

I would like to get these matches:

```
1. 
name =  i.want.this.as.name.
year =  2014
seasonepisode =     s01e02
season =    01
episode =   02
2.
name = i still want a this
year = 2010
3.
name = i also want this
4.
name =  I still want this
seasonepisode =     s05e23
season =    05
episode =   23
```

Right now, i have this regexp:

```
(?<name>.*)(?<year>\d{4})(\s|\.|\z)*(?<seasonepisode>s(?<season>\d{1,2})e(?<episode>\d{1,2}))*
```

But I only get the desired result on the first string. I guess that is because there are no matches for the full regexp in the string 2, 3 or 4.

Here you can try the regexp: http://rubular.com/r/1ypseJ7c6I

So my question is, how do I tell the regexp that i dont require matches on everything, just something? :-) I have tried added asterix to the opitonal.

5€ donation to a project / charity of your choice for the correct answer :-)

Comment: Don't start with your attempted regex, or worse, a link to that. Start with explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: moved the link to bottom...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work: http://rubular.com/r/4qYuzGGqaB. Using `/ix` options, the latter for readability.

```
^
(?<nm>.+?)        # Name: at least one character, non-greedy.
(?<yr>\d{4})?     # Year, optional.
(?:               # Post-year stuff, non-captured.
  [\s\.]
  s(?<se>\d\d?)   # Season.
  e(?<ep>\d\d?)   # Episode.
  (?<rest>.*)     # The rest, optional.
)?                # Post-year stuff is optional.
$                 # Must consume full line.
```

A couple of notes:

- The non-greediness of the name-group is important. Otherwise, it will happily consume the entire line (everything else is optional).
- Requiring a full line match is also important. Otherwise, the pattern will happily match only the first letter of the line (the name is non-greedy, everything else is optional).

Comment: Works really great! Where do you want me to send small donation?

Comment: @MarcusBrunsten I appreciate that: let's make it your choice.

Comment: hmm,  after some trying it doesnt seem to work with some of my data, i dont really see the difference. but check the last row in this example: http://rubular.com/r/8lawUjVber
. 
on other notes: http://i.imgur.com/mW4A7PI.png ( sry its in swedish )

Comment: @MarcusBrunsten Yeah, I wondered about an example like that. It's often difficult to get these patterns where most of the items are optional to do-what-you-want in all cases. Sometimes a better strategy is to write several simple regexes (each having either no, or at most one, optional element) and try each one in turn, starting with the most specific and ending with the most general. Start with a regex containing everything (with an optional rest-group). If that fails, go for name+year+rest. If that fails, go for name+year. If that fails, go for name only.

Comment: Ok, thats too bad. you were so close :-) thanks anyway!